# How to get rid of address bar and bottom bar in Flutter 'WebBrowser' Plugin?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

My App is a Flutter WEB app.
This is the plugin I am using to display some HTML coming from the server:

https://pub.dev/packages/web_browser

Here is the code I am using:

```
  WebBrowser( 
initialUrl: 'https://${Provider.of<CP>(context).getPaymentURL()+Provider.of<CP>(context).getPaymentPATH()}?O=${Provider.of<CP>(context).getOrder().orderUID}&Ro=${Provider.of<CP>(context).getOrder().res_key}',
```

),

My screen looks like below:

[image]

I would like to rid of the address bar and bottom bar but not sure how. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use attribute `interactionSettings` and set `WebBrowserInteractionSettings`'s `topBar` and `bottomBar` to `SizedBox.shrink()`

code snippet

```
return WebBrowser(
        initialUrl: 'https://dart.dev/',
        interactionSettings: WebBrowserInteractionSettings(
            topBar: SizedBox.shrink(), bottomBar: SizedBox.shrink()));
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_browser/web_browser.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebBrowser(
        initialUrl: 'https://dart.dev/',
        interactionSettings: WebBrowserInteractionSettings(
            topBar: SizedBox.shrink(), bottomBar: SizedBox.shrink()));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Demo"),
          ),
          body: MyWidget()),
    );
  }
}
```